# Sybase is sustituting some specials characters for "\1xA"

Tags: unicode, sybase, sap-iq

I have a problem between two enviroments in Sybase IQ

The procedure in pre-production enviroment the specials characters are correct inserted and they look like this (ä)

```
   case when  MyColum = "Something schäft" then X
```

In produccion nerverless when i look the procedure its writing.

```
      case when  MyColum = "Something  \x1A ft" then X
```

Could somebody tell me the root of the problem?

Thanks in advance, Enrique

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is not in Sybase, its your editor.

with following query you can check which encoding is set on your sybase

```
SELECT DB_PROPERTY( 'CharSet' );
```

the result is for example ISO_8859

your texteditor should set the self encoding.. and not UTF8 or something other

Comment: But it doesnt explain why in Pre production is correct and why in production no.  Both are Sybase and both comen from the same editor.

Comment: Maybe you don't have exact the same sybase version on both environments

Comment: I see, apparently pre und production they are not they have difference verstions.